# Why HashMap initial capacity is not properly handled by the library?

Tags: java, hashmap, capacity

To create HashMap/HashSet for N elements, we generally do`new HashMap((int)(N/0.75F)+1)` which is annoying.

Why the library has not taken care of this in the first place and allows initialization like `new HashMap(N)`(should not rehash till N elements) taking care of this calculation `(int)(N/0.75F)+1`?

**Update 09 Nov 22:**

Java 19 introduced [HashMap<K,V> newHashMap(int numMappings)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#newHashMap(int))

Javadoc:

> Creates a new, empty HashMap suitable for the expected number of mappings. The returned map uses the default load factor of 0.75, and its initial capacity is generally large enough so that the expected number of mappings can be added without resizing the map.

Similar methods were introduced in other Map classes too.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is because the HashMap does as you say it should do.

Comment: The overload with just a number specifies the size including the free space. Venkata wanted it to be the number of entries before rehashing. The library developers made the other choice. No point debating this now anymore.

Comment: @jackrabit You got it right. I just wanted to know is there any technical reason, why it is designed such a way.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Updating to reflect changed question. No, there is no such standard API but it seems there is a method [`Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)) in [guava](/questions/tagged/guava):

> Creates a `HashMap` instance, with a high enough "initial capacity" that it *should* hold `expectedSize` elements without growth.

---

> i have to initialize it to (int)(N/0.75F)+1

No you don't. If you create new `HashMap` from other `Map`, `HashMap` calculates capacity first by default:

```
public HashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    this(Math.max((int) (m.size() / DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR) + 1,
                  DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY), DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
    putAllForCreate(m);
}
```

If you add elements one by one, the same process happens as well:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    if ((size >= threshold) && (null != table[bucketIndex])) {
        resize(2 * table.length);
        //...
    }

    createEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
}
```

The only reason to use `HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)` constructor is when you know from the very beginning how many elements you want to store in the `HashMap`, thus avoiding resizing and rehashing later (map has correct size from the very beginning).

One interesting implementation detail is that initial capacity is trimmed to the nearest power of two (see: [Why ArrayList grows at a rate of 1.5, but for Hashmap it's 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040753)):

```
// Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
int capacity = 1;
while (capacity < initialCapacity)
    capacity <<= 1;
```

So if you want your `HashMap` to have exact capacity as defined, just use powers of two.

Choosing different `loadFactor` allows you to trade space for performance - smaller value means more memory, but less collisions.

Comment: I'm talking about only this case `new HashMap(N)`, because this is ehat we use 99% of times.

Comment: @VenkataRaju: I believe based on your comments that you have an issue with rounding `N` to the nearest power of two (?), see updates to my answer.

Comment: @VenkataRaju: looks like [`Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int)) is what you need, see my update.

Comment: You got it right. I just wanted to know is there any technical reason, why it is designed such a way.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the following program

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    for (int i = 12; i < 80; i++) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>((int) Math.ceil(i / 0.75));
        int beforeAdding = Array.getLength(getField(map, "table"));
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) map.put(j, j);
        int afterAdding = Array.getLength(getField(map, "table"));
        map.put(i, i);
        int oneMore = Array.getLength(getField(map, "table"));
        System.out.printf("%,d: initial %,d, after N %,d, after N+1 %,d%n ",
                i, beforeAdding, afterAdding, oneMore);
    }
}

private static <T> T getField(Map<Integer, Integer> map, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field table = map.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    table.setAccessible(true);
    return (T) table.get(map);
}
```

which prints out

```
 12: initial 16, after N 16, after N+1 32
 13: initial 32, after N 32, after N+1 32
 .. deleted ..
 24: initial 32, after N 32, after N+1 64
 25: initial 64, after N 64, after N+1 64
 .. deleted ..
 47: initial 64, after N 64, after N+1 64
 48: initial 64, after N 64, after N+1 128
 49: initial 128, after N 128, after N+1 128
 .. deleted ..
 79: initial 128, after N 128, after N+1 128
```

This shows that the default initialiser the initial capacity is rounded to the next power of two.  The problem with this value is that if you want this to be the eventual size, you have to take into account the load factor if you want to avoid resizing.  Ideally you shouldn't have to, in the way the Map copy constructor does for you.

Comment: @VenkataRaju Thank you for the link. It is redundant.  You only need to specify N as the initial capacity.

Comment: **You only need to specify N as the initial capacity**  Hmm.. i don't think so, then why is Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(int expectedSize) existed? See updated reply from @Tomasz

Comment: @VenkataRaju I think I see your point now. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations grow automatically as you add more elements. The performance of most implementations also tends to decrease when the containers get fuller. That's why there is a load factor in the first place: to leave some empty space available.

Comment: Hmm..  not sure whether you understood the question. If i create a  `new HashMap(N)`, i'll assume that it will not grow/rehashing won't happen till i put N+1 element, but the reality is that, rehashing will happens before that. To prevent rehashing, we will initialize like `new HashMap((int)(N/0.75F)+1)`. Now my question is the library would have taken care of this and allow us to use `new HashMap(N))` and take care this calculation internally.

Comment: That totally was not clear from your question. See Tomasz' answer. They must have thought that yours is an uncommon use case that can be easily implemented if you need it.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot even be sure rehashing doesn't occur when initialising like that. Do you really have a (measurable) issue with rehashing here, or are you just afraid to loose performance if it happens? Otherwise this seems like a case of premature optimization...